# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 when I run my web service client

Tags: apache-axis, rampart

I create a Dynamic web project  with name   'testUpdate' (and of course I don't forget to  change the dynamic web module version to 2.5 and in configuration  I choose Axis 2 web service

1. I add to my Dynamic web project these two classes :

SimpleService .java   and   PWCBHandler.java

1. I right click on SimpleService.java -> New ->Other -> Web Service  to create my web service
2. I don't forget to copy all the jar files from rampart distribution to testUpdate/ WebContent/WEB_INF/lib  and all  .mar modules into testUpdate/ WebContent/WEB_INF/modules
3. I change services.xml file so it looks like

   ```
   <service name="SimpleService" >
   <module ref="rampart" />
   <Description>

   </Description>
   <messageReceivers>
       <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-only" class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver" />
       <messageReceiver  mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out"  class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/>
   </messageReceivers>
   <parameter name="ServiceClass" locked="false">com.gismo.SimpleService</parameter>
       <parameter name="InflowSecurity">
       <action>
           <items>UsernameToken</items>
           <passwordCallbackClass>com.gismo.PWCBHandler</passwordCallbackClass>
       </action>
   </parameter>
   </service>
   ```
4. I right click on testUpdate -> RUN AS _> Run on Server (and my web service is deployed successfully)
5. File -> New ->  Other -> Web Service Client

and in Service Definition I paste the url of the wsdl file of SimpleService

( `http://localhost:9091/testUpdate/services/SimpleService?wsdl`)

1. I add  testcl.java class to my web-service client. Here is the code

   ```
   public class testCL {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

   if (args.length != 2) {

       System.out.println(args.length);
       System.out
               .println("Usage: $java Client endpoint_address client_repo_path");
   }

   ConfigurationContext ctx = ConfigurationContextFactory
           .createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(args[1], args[1]
                   + "/conf/axis2.xml");

   ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient(ctx, null);
   Options options = new Options();
   options.setAction("urn:echo");
   options.setTo(new EndpointReference(args[0]));
   client.setOptions(options);

   OMElement response = client.sendReceive(getPayload("Hello world"));

   System.out.println(response);
   }

     private static OMElement getPayload(String value) {
    OMFactory factory = OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory();
    OMNamespace ns = factory.createOMNamespace("com.gismo/xsd", "ns1");
    OMElement elem = factory.createOMElement("echo", ns);
    OMElement childElem = factory.createOMElement("param0", null);
    childElem.setText(value);
    elem.addChild(childElem);
    return elem;
   }
   }
   ```
2. I don't forget to change webSercice_client/WebContent/axis2-web/conf/axis2.xml  and  add

   ```
    <module ref="rampart"/>
    <parameter name="OutflowSecurity">
     <action>
       <items>UsernameToken</items>
       <user>bob</user>
        <passwordCallbackClass>com.gismo.PWCBHandler</passwordCallbackClass>
     </action>
    </parameter>
   ```
3. But when I run testCl  as Java Application it gives me an exception

   Usage: $java Client endpoint_address client_repo_path
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
       at com.gismo.testcl.main(testcl.java:24)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My psychic debugging powers tell me that you ran it without providing two command-line arguments. You can see the error message "Usage: $java Client endpoint_address client_repo_path" is present in your program output, meaning that you didn't supply two command-line arguments, so `args[1]` may not be valid. Your program doesn't exit after checking the number of command-line arguments, so it tries to access `args[1]` after complaining that the program was run incorrectly.

```
if (args.length != 2) {

    System.out.println(args.length);
    System.out
            .println("Usage: $java Client endpoint_address client_repo_path");
}

ConfigurationContext ctx = ConfigurationContextFactory
        .createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(args[1], args[1]
                + "/conf/axis2.xml");
```

Comment: yes that was the problem!! I learned hoe to provide command line arguments in eclipse this morning ! Unfortunately now it tells me that it can't find my password callback class;  with these exceptions java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.gismo.PWCBHandler    org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: class com.gismo.PWCBHandler